# $f:X\times \Bbb R^n\to X\times \Bbb R^n$ is a continuous map satisfying $f(x,v)=(x,A(x)v)$ for $x\in X$ and $v\in \Bbb R^n$ then $A$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

Suppose $X$ is a topological space, and that $f:X\times \Bbb R^n\to X\times \Bbb R^n$ is a continuous map satisfying $f(x,v)=(x,A(x)v)$ for $x\in X$ and $v\in \Bbb R^n$, where $A(x)$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, depending on $x\in X$. I want to show that $A$ is a continuous function of $x$ ($X\to \Bbb R^{n\times n}$), but I have no idea.  Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that the maps $x\mapsto \text{col}_i(A(x))$ (the $i$th column of $A(x)$) are continuous, for $1\le i\le n$.

Fix such an $i$.

Let $\pi:X\times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the projection onto the second coordinate. By definition of the product topology, $\pi$ is continuous.

Let $g: X\to X\times\mathbb{R}^n$ be defined by $g(x)=(x,e_i)$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th canonical vector. Note that $g$ is continuous.

Now observe that $x\mapsto \text {col}_i(A(x))$ is exactly the same as the 
composition

$$
X\xrightarrow{g}X\times \mathbb{R}^n\xrightarrow{f}X\times\mathbb{R}^n \xrightarrow{\pi}\mathbb{R}^n
$$